# Create an array with different sales created at the same time Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, time, timestamp

Were trying to create an array grouping sales by the time they were created at and the person who made the sale. 
Here's what we have so far:

```
@sales = Sales.select("date(created_at) as ordered_date").group("DATE_PART('hour', created_at)")
```

We have a table with sales that has a created_at field with a timestamp. It also has a client_id where we can make sure that we are grouping by the person that made the sale.

How can we create an array that works?
We're fairly new to rails so easy explanations are appreciated.

Using: Ruby on Rails 4, PostreSQL

Following is the snapshot of the error. The code on top is the index and the bottom is the error.

[image: error screen]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group ***all*** of your sales you should be able to do:

```
Sales.all.group(:client_id, :created_at)
```

Or if you're trying to group by `:created_at` and then `:client_id` just switch the order.  Though just a note, I would not recommend grouping by `:created_at` since, unless your processing ***tons*** of transaction, you will rarely have the duplicate times. You don't need to write raw SQL since ActiveRecord handles the SQL query based on what adapter you have defined in you database file.

Comment: He says he wants to group them by the hour of created_at, not the second, which addresses your duplicate time concern.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that this line won't return a vanilla "array" but rather an [`ActiveRecord::Association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks @MaxWilliams, missed that part.  I **think** `Sales.all.group(["DATE_PART('hour', created_at)", :client_id])` should work in that case.

Comment: Thanks @mattforni, tried your code but keep getting the error:uninitialized constant VistaventasController::Sales

Comment: You should be saying `Sale.select` not `Sales.select` - Sale is the class name.  That's what that error is telling you.

Comment: That's probably because your model is named `Sale` or at least it should be by Rails conventions.  By conventions model names are singular and controller names are plural.  I was just going off the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! But we get a new error... On our index.html.erb for the view that we are trying to create, we have this code:

Comment: <div class="productos-display">
 
    <% @sales.each do |sale|%>
    <h2><%= link_to sale.client_id, store_ventas_path(sale) %></h2>
    <%end%>

Comment: and we get this error on it:  Showing /home/mariorozco12/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/CAS_Uniformes/app/views/vistaventas/index.html.erb where line #32 raised:

PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "sales.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales"  GROUP BY DATE_PART('hour', cr...
               ^
: SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales"  GROUP BY DATE_PART('hour', created_at), client_id

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the error?  I think something was lost in translation.

Comment: @mattforni I posted the link to the image on a new answer

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, doing the group as part of the find never really gives me what i want.  It's generally better to get them all and then group them afterwards using `Array#group_by`.  Then, in the group you have a series of arrays which you can iterate over.  Something like this:

```
#in Sale model - convenience method
def created_at_hour
  Time.at((self.created_at.to_f / 1.hour).round * 1.hour)
end

#controller
@grouped_sales = Sales.order(:created_at).group_by(&:created_at_hour)

#view
<% #the hash keys *should* be in time order but just in case, let's order them %>
<% @grouped_sales.keys.sort.each do |time| %>
  <div class="sale-group">
    <h3><%= time.strftime("%H:00, %d/%m/%Y") %></h3>
    <%  @grouped_sales[time].each do |sale| %>
      <div class="sale">
       <!-- sale html -->
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT - whoops, forgot to close a div :)